# ошибка создания слота qt python

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, gui, pyside2

создаю кнопку на форме. тыкаю по ней правой кнопкой мыши -> перейти к слоту -> clicked -> ОК. вылетает такая ошибка:

> Не удалось найти документы соответствующие «ui_form.h». Возможно, пересборка проекта поможет.

пересборка не помогает:)
подскажите, в чем может быть дело?

вот код, который запускают. сам код запускается.

```
# This Python file uses the following encoding: utf-8
import sys
import os


from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader


class pygui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(pygui, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = pygui()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

код ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>pygui</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="pygui">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>371</width>
    <height>167</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>pygui</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>140</x>
     <y>70</y>
     <width>75</width>
     <height>23</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Не совсем понимаю, что вы написали, но попробуйте еще раз. Раскомментируйте строки для `PySide2` и закомментируйте строки для `PyQt5`.

```
import sys
import os
'''
from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import QFile
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
'''
from PyQt5.Qt import *                                            # PyQt5
from PyQt5 import uic                                             # PyQt5


class PyGui(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PyGui, self).__init__()
        self.load_ui()

    def load_ui(self):
        '''
        loader = QUiLoader()
        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "form.ui")
        ui_file = QFile(path)
        ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
        loader.load(ui_file, self)
        ui_file.close()
        '''

#        self.ui = QUiLoader().load("form.ui", self)               # PySide2
        uic.loadUi("form_q1273984.ui", self)                       # PyQt5  

#        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)        # PySide2
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)            # PyQt5 

    def onClicked(self):
        print(f'onClicked')    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication([])
    widget = PyGui()
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо за ответ! видимо, я слишком многого хочу:) когда кодил в qt на плюсах, была возможность нажать по элементу на форме правой кнопкой мыши и создать слот. в питоне, походу, нужно коннектить элементы ручками:)